# RavenDB-2.5 database restore process throwing error "Database already exists, cannot restore to an existing database"

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I followed [URL](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/server/administration/backup-restore) to do database backup and restore process of RavenDB 2.5 but it has throwing error in every computer while restoring database only. I can successfully backup my database but not able to restore.

**URL:** [Backup and Restore RavenDB 2.5](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/server/administration/backup-restore)

**Error:**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\RavenDB>Raven.Server.exe -src C:\Users\AppUser1\Desktop\Backup -dest C:\Program Files (x86)\RavenDB\Databases\Test171015 -restore
>
> Error: Database already exists, cannot restore to an existing database.
>   Error: Restore Canceled
>   System.IO.IOException: Database already exists, cannot restore to an existing database.
>
> at Raven.Storage.Esent.Backup.RestoreOperation.Execute()
>   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Restore(RavenConfiguration configuration, String backupLocation, String databaseLocation, Action`1 output, Boolean defrag)
>   at Raven.Server.Program.RunRestoreOperation(String backupLocation, String databaseLocation, Boolean defrag)

I removed database from the panel, removed data from the folder, removed database folder from "Databases" folder but does not able to identify what's going wrong and what I'm missing?

Comment: To restore backups with Esent, you'll need to make sure that the user is the _owner_ of the backup files

Comment: @AyendeRahien I'm using Windows's command prompt for backup and restore databases. Can you please clear me for `owner`? Is it RavenDB Database Owner OR Windows' User? Is there any RavenDB syntax to take backup using `owner`?

Comment: This is the windows owner in the file permissions